# onShow Lifecycle Function Is Not Triggered in QuickApp?

Tags: javascript, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have a quick app that im writing which contains a quick app page that references only a single custom element through the router.push API, the onShow lifecycle function for that page cannot be triggered.

```
<import name="listone" src="./aa.ux"></import>
<template>
  <!-- The template can contain only one root node. -->
<listone></listone>
</template>
<script>
  import prompt from '@system.prompt'
  export default {
    private: {
    },
    onInit: function() {
    },
    onShow() {
      console.log('Enter a string whatever you like.');
      prompt.showToast({
        message: 'Enter a string whatever you like.'
      })
    }, // This function cannot be triggered.
  }
</script>
<style>
  .demo-page {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .title {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>
```

And my aa.ux file

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <text> Enter some words.</text>
    <text>Enter some words.</text>
    <text>Enter some words.</text>
    <text>Enter some words.</text>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
 .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #00fa9a;
  }
</style>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: {
    },
    onInit() {
    },
  }
</script>
```

How can i get the onShow function to trigger in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten to the 'root' of the issue, the quick app loader does not trigger the onShow lifecycle function if the root node of the page is a custom element. However, the function can be triggered for a subelement. SO the way to get round this for me was to add an extra div element like:

```
<template>
  <!-- The template can contain only one root node. -->
  <div>
    <listone></listone>
  </div>
</template>
```